# Agrupamiento con Rangos sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, msql

Estoy tratando de agrupar registros por rango de edades, [10-19] [20-29][30- mas] para ello hago la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (edad BETWEEN 10 AND 19) THEN 'De 10 a 19' ELSE
        CASE WHEN (edad BETWEEN 20 AND 29) THEN 'De 20 a 29' ELSE
            CASE WHEN (edad >= 30) THEN 'De 30 o más'
            END
        END
    end rango, count(*) as total
    FROM Employees
    group by rango
```

pero obtengo el siguiente error, cabe mencionar que hago un case, debido a que en la tabla no hay rangos, solo hay edades.

```
Invalid column name 'rango'.
```

La tabla tiene nombre y edad (int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el nombre `rango` se "materializa" al final de la consulta, cuando ya se debería haber resuelto el `GROUP BY`, es decir, al agrupar, todavía no existe la columna `rango`, hay dos formas de resolverlo:

A. Repitiendo la lógica de la columna

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (edad BETWEEN 10 AND 19) THEN 'De 10 a 19' 
             WHEN (edad BETWEEN 20 AND 29) THEN 'De 20 a 29' 
             ELSE 'De 30 o más'
        END  as rango, 
        count(*) as total
        FROM Employees
        group by CASE WHEN (edad BETWEEN 10 AND 19) THEN 'De 10 a 19' 
                      WHEN (edad BETWEEN 20 AND 29) THEN 'De 20 a 29' 
                      ELSE 'De 30 o más'
                 END
```

B. Mediante una subconsulta que "materializa" en primer lugar el nombre

```
SELECT T.rango,
       count(*) as total
       FROM (SELECT  CASE WHEN (edad BETWEEN 10 AND 19) THEN 'De 10 a 19' 
                          WHEN (edad BETWEEN 20 AND 29) THEN 'De 20 a 29' 
                          ELSE 'De 30 o más'
                      END  as rango   
                      FROM Employees
          ) T
       GROUP BY T.rango
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción podría ser utilizar UNION y en cada query calcular el total de determinado rango:

```
SELECT 'De 10 a 19' AS rango, count(*) AS total
FROM Employees
WHERE edad BETWEEN 10 AND 19

UNION ALL

SELECT 'De 20 a 29' AS rango, count(*) AS total
FROM Employees
WHERE edad BETWEEN 20 AND 29

UNION ALL

SELECT 'De 30 o más' AS rango, count(*) AS total
FROM Employees
WHERE edad >= 30;
```